# Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration in spring boot when using Spring JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jparepository

Good day,

I am doing a Spring Boot Application in my Eclipse IDE. When I right click on my SpringBoot Application file and run as Java application, I hitting error as follow:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field tutorialRepository in com.utility.tool.ToolApplication required a bean of type 'com.utility.tool.repository.TutorialRepository' that could not be found.

```
The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.utility.tool.repository.TutorialRepository' in your configuration.
```

Then I found that I forget to include the spring boot starter data jar. Hence, I add the following code in my `build.gradle` and it finally run correctly:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.5'
```

Then I right click my project and export jar as runnable jar, and then try to run it by `java -jar my.jar`, and it hit back the error.

I open the jar in `JdGui`, and found that the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.5.jar` is inside. May I know what is my mistake? My jar structure is something as follow:

[image]

The jar is in the list but is at bottom, thus not in my screen shot.

Comment: Not sure how you made that jar but that isn't a proper Spring Boot jar. Use the build tool you are using (maven or gradle) to provide the jar not the export to jar functionin your IDE.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using gradle, any place I can get a sample for Spring Boot?

Comment: Check the documentaiton, just do `./gradlew build` and the resulting jar is the correct one.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum, u are right. its actually just simple gradle build will generate the jar correctly. At first need tricky job on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SpringBoot annotations. You may be missing some `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Component` annotations.